# ɔθɛntɪket translating from IPA to English

Tags: english

Having trouble translating this word into English if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest: authenticate

Answer (score 4):

The word is *authenticate*. That transliteration isn't so good though, I would suggest /ɔˈθɛntɪkeɪt/.

Comment: Transliteration to IPA will depend a lot on the speaker's accent/dialect, and even if you want to suggest a 'standard' pronunciation to base your transliteration on, you will have to define which one to use, e.g. from North America, southern England, northern England/Scotland, Ireland, South Africa, Australia, New Zealand, India, … — the possibilities are almost endless.

Comment: @dumetrulo, sure, but I don't know anyone who'd pronounce the last syllable as /ket/. That looks like a short vowel to me.

Comment: Off the top of my head, Indian or Pakistani English comes to mind; I speak to enough people from these regions on a weekly basis to be quite sure about that. Granted, you would think a short vowel in an unstressed position should be pronounced /ə/ or similar, and if it's /e/ it should rather be a long vowel, but especially non-native speakers from regions with languages where vowel length is not a language feature might not make this difference.